# Phased Array System ToolBox. Overview

Tags: simulation, matlab

I have a requirement where in I need to simulate a radar in real time. I am yet to start with Phased array system toolbox (waiting for evaluation license), but I had few questions about the this toolbox. It will be really helpful if you can answer them.

1. Does the tool box supports real time simulation
2. Support for the environment. What environmental factors it takes into consideration.
3. Support for fluctuating RCS.
4. Support for tracking the targets.
5. Support for transponder and skin modes.

I will start with the study once I get my hands on the toolbox but till then any inputs here will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Depending on how satisfied you are with the answers provided, this is something which you can contact MathWorks about directly.  There is actually an entire department devoted to answering these sorts of questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Phased Array System Toolbox is a very niche product, and I doubt you'll find much experience with it available on StackOverflow. Even within MathWorks there are only a handful of people who know anything about it.

Nevertheless, I would recommend that the best (in fact only) way to find out any details of it would be to contact MathWorks directly. If you'd rather not contact them via Sales yet, you can contact John Zhao, the Phased Array System Toolbox Technical Expert (one of the handful described above) directly via the product's [Contact The Expert page](https://www.mathworks.com/products/phased-array/expert-contact.html).

I can tell you that since it is a System Toolbox, it will be providing much of its functionality via System Objects, which are typically designed to support real-time code generation when used together with MATLAB Coder. I have no idea about your questions 2-5.

Comment: Thanks, there is indeed a scarcity on the details about the tool box.Thanks for listing the contacts. Will get in touch with them.